# Retrieve selected value from Drop Down List in Excel (created in C#)

Tags: c#, excel, list, validation

I am creating an Excel sheet in C# that has drop down list. Once the spreadsheet is created there is no way to access the selected values from the list (non-programatically). When I use data validation to create a list in excel it works fine. The list created in C# seem to be different. In the picture you can see that the value in cell AE should be the selected value of Z4, however, it shows 0.

[image: Excel sheet]

The current code I am using is

```
    public static void CreateList(Worksheet sheet, string[] items, int col, string row)
    {
        Range xlsRange;
        DropDowns xlDropDowns;
        DropDown xlDropDown;

        xlsRange = sheet.get_Range(col + row, col + row);
        xlDropDowns = ((DropDowns)(sheet.DropDowns(Type.Missing)));

        xlDropDown = xlDropDowns.Add((double)xlsRange.Left, (double)xlsRange.Top, (double)xlsRange.Width, (double)xlsRange.Height, true);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            xlDropDown.AddItem(items[i], i + 1);
    }
```

I also tried to due data validation with the following code, but I get unrecoverable errors when I try to open the excel spreadsheet

```
        public static void CreateList(Worksheet sheet, string[] items, int col, int row)
    {
        var flatList = string.Join(",", items);
        var cell = (Range)sheet.Cells[row, col];
        cell.Validation.Delete();
        cell.Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, flatList, Type.Missing);

        cell.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
        cell.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why the  "excel found unreadable content" error occurs when I use drop down list. The comma separated string was too long in one of the drop downs. So both sets of code work. The first is for combo boxes which you can only retrieve indices of selected values using format control on each one. The second is a drop down (validation) that cannot be created with a string that is too long.